# ggplot density plot from data.frame that holds moments

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a mean and a standard deviation, it is easy to plot a Gaussian density using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(-3, 3)), aes(x)) +
       stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

This example returns a density plot for the standard normal distribution. I have a data set that is somewhat more complex:

```
m = c(1, 1.5, 3, 3.5)     # means of gaussians
s = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7) # standard deviations of gaussians
g = c("A", "A", "B", "B") # group
v = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y") # class 


plot.df = data.frame(m = m,
                     s = s,
                     g = g,
                     v = v)
```

where `m` are the means of Gaussians and `s` are the corresponding standard deviations. I'd like to use `facet_grid` for the group variable `g` and `color` of the densities should depend on the class `v`. I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this without manually setting a legend for `color` and copy-pasting `stat_function` for every single density.

Edit: Just to be clear, the ideal solution should generalize to an arbitrary number of groups and in the best case also to an arbitrary number of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the automated variant of manually creating multiple `stat_functions()` for every parameter.

For example, write a function that takes your values as input and produces a list of `stat_function()`s.

```
multidensity <- function(mu, sd, group, class, range = c(-3, 3)) {
  mapply(function(mu, sd, group, class) {
    stat_function(
      data = data.frame(group = group, class = class, x = range),
      aes(x = x, colour = class),
      fun = dnorm,
      args = list(mean = mu, sd = sd),
      inherit.aes = FALSE
    )
  }, mu = mu, sd = sd, group = group, class = class,
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
```

Then, simply call function when needed.

```
m = c(1, 1.5, 3, 3.5)     # means of gaussians
s = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7) # standard deviations of gaussians
g = c("A", "A", "B", "B") # group
v = c("X", "Y", "X", "Y") # class 

ggplot() +
  multidensity(m, s, g, v, range = c(0, 5)) +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
```

[image]